# In NestJS, how do you inject Dynamic modules async options to module internal imports?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

In **Nestjs** if I have a Dynamic Module *A* that accepts an `options` object as per forRootAsync logic, how do I inject that `options` to its imported modules? (lest's say *module A* imports *module B* which depends on some of Module A options)

I know how to inject the options object to modules A `providers` but how do you inject it to Module A imported modules?

note: to inject the options to module A imported providers I can wrap the options object using a [value provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#value-providers-usevalue) and use the inject capabilities of [Factory providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory), to make it available to the provider

Answer (score 1):

If `ModuleB` is imported into `ModuleA`, and depends on `ModuleA`'s options, then you're going to have a [circular dependency](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) between `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. Technically this is doable, you'll need to forward reference both modules to each other, export the options provider from `ModuleA` and import `ModuleA` in `ModuleB` so that the options provider is available. It's definitely going to get messy as DynamicModules on their own are no walk in the park. You may want to see if you can work out a different architecture and see if you can avoid the circular dependency.